# Regex pattern to retrieve key and value

Tags: python, regex

I have a question regarding regex in Python.

I have key-value pairs separated by `|` such as this:

`"key1: value | key2: value"`

I need help to retrieve the keys and the values for each pairs using regex patterns:

```
>>> import re
>>> value_pairs = "key1: value | key2: value"
>>> pairs = re.match('regex-pattern', value_pairs)
>>> print pairs
(key1, value)
(key2, value)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) to get multiple matches:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "key1: value | key2: value"
>>> re.findall(r'([^\s|:]+):\s*([^\s|:]+)', s)
[('key1', 'value'), ('key2', 'value')]
```

As you can see in the above example, `re.findall` returns a list of tuples if there are multiple groups in the pattern.

Comment: thanks for the solution. How can I modify the regex if the value has more than 1 token, for example if I have `key1: coca cola` this current regex will return `[('key', 'coca')]` but I wish to return `[('key', 'coca cola')]`

Comment: @Juli, Try `[(key, value.strip()) for key, value in re.findall(r'([^\s|:]+):\s*([^|:]+)', s)]`

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this without a regex:

```
>>> value_pairs = "key1: value | key2: value"
>>> dict([ex.strip() for ex in e.split(':')] for e in value_pairs.split('|'))
{'key2': 'value', 'key1': 'value'}
```

Which works for a longer groups of pairs as well:

```
>>> value_pairs = "key1: value1 | key2: value 2 | key3: value3"
>>> dict([ex.strip() for ex in e.split(':')] for e in value_pairs.split('|'))
{'key3': 'value3', 'key2': 'value 2', 'key1': 'value1'}
```

Comment: +1 You don't really need the extra outer [] in dict().